SQL - Columns merge and grouping by column name while summation of the other column
I have a question related to the SQL query. The data looks like this:



Name1
Name2
Category
Total




ABC
NULL
Category1
100


DEF
ABC
Category1
20


GHI
ABC
Category3
300


XYZ
DEF
Category2
60


XYZ
GHI
Category3
80


NULL
NULL
Category2
90



I am trying to merge the Name1 and Name2 and grouping them based on Category with the Total having the sum if same name have same categories.
Thanks in advance
The method I tried were this (kinda similar to these two queries asked in stackoverflow):
Match two columns and add the third column in SQL
SQL: GROUP BY column B for groups in column a
pysqldf = lambda q1: sqldf(q1, globals())
q1 = """SELECT Name, SUM(Total) AS Total
FROM
(
    SELECT Name1 AS Name, SUM(Total) AS Total
    FROM df
    WHERE Name1 IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY Name1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Name2, SUM(Total)
    FROM df
    WHERE Name2 IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY Name2
) t
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Name"""
df2 = pysqldf(q1)

Tried in pandas also but it gives different results with the following command:
df2 = df.groupby(['investigator','second_investigator','requested_test']).agg({'Count': 'sum'})

The output required is like this:



Name
Category
Total




ABC
Category1
120


ABC
Category3
300


DEF
Category1
20


DEF
Category2
60


GHI
Category3
380


XYZ
Category2
60


XYZ
Category3
80




I am surprised your query even syntaxes given there is no column called name , shouldn't that be user?

Yes, that's right. I was editing something and made this mistake...

If the question can be closed please do so if you still have an issue after correction please amend the code in the question.

No, I am still unable to solve it as couldn't do it based on category. Cannot get the desired output

You aren't grouping by category...and you can have more than 1 term in a group by.

SELECT Name, Category, SUM(Total) AS Total
FROM
(
    SELECT Name1 AS Name, Category, SUM(Total) AS Total
    FROM df
    WHERE Name1 IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY 1, 2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Name2, Category, SUM(Total)
    FROM df
    WHERE Name2 IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY 1, 2
) t
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 1

fiddle
